# Code for downloading video files

Tags: php

I am working on a project and was wondering how the code for downloading video files is like. I have an idea but it is half of the bigger picture.I am coding in php and jquery.

Comment: What do you mean by "code for downloading video files"?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what is being asked here.  You want to serve up video files for download?  You want to download some from another site?  You want to put a client-side player on your page?

Comment: A bit more information about what you're trying to do will help people answer your question and get what you want quicker. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply link to them in either PHP or jQuery and then visitor to the site can click to download them; this is complicated by the server/client model of served pages, in that you're trying to get the client to download the videos, not the server.

Also, if their default viewer is something like Windows Media Player, this will manage the downloading for you/them.

Unless you're talking about embedding the video into the page and streaming the content when the page loads, or an event is fired (jQuery, etc)?

Hope this helps.